# Lines before form.save() are not saving the right values

Tags: python, django

I have a view with model form, the `ModelForm` doesn't really contain all fields in the model. other fields I've used the methods of `form.field = value` before `form.save()`, but all of this fields being saved as default. none take the value am trying to give. here are the code :

```
def PostAd(request):
    ad_post_form = AdPostForm()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        obj = Account.objects.get(user=request.user)
        if request.method == "POST":
            ad_post_form = AdPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if ad_post_form.is_valid():
                ad_post_form.created_by = request.user
                if obj.role == 'admin':
                    ad_post_form.is_active = True
                ad_post_form.save()
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            ad_post_form = AdPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            ad_post_form = AdPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if ad_post_form.is_valid():
                otp_number = random.randint(100000, 999999)
                ad_post_form.otp = otp_number
                ad_post_form.is_activated = False
                ad_post_form.save()
                current_id = ad_post_form.id
                current_contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email')
                email_url_active = str(settings.URL_LOCAL) + 'new_ad/adidnumberis' + str(
                    current_id) + '/needactivate/activate/' + str(otp_number) + '/'
                email_msg = "Please Confirm adding the Ad to Jehlum. Click link " + email_url_active
                email = EmailMessage('Active Email', email_msg, to=[current_contact_email])
                email.send()
                return redirect('home')

            else:
                ad_post_form = AdPostForm()

    context = {
        'ad_post_form': ad_post_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'pages/post-ad.html', context)
```

the problem is `ad_post_form.is_active = True` is being saved as False(default)
also `ad_post_form.otp = otp_number` is being saved as 0 (default) and i need to give the spicific values i assigned here .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the model instance and set the attributes there. You so this by calling save with commit=False.

```
if ad_post_form.is_valid():
    ad_post = ad_post_form.save(commit=False)
    ad_post.created_by = request.user
    ...
    ad_post.save()
```